# How “reindexing” the dataframe with min_date and max_date value

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

```
             Q   Mod
Date        
2007-01-02  8.0 3900.0
2007-01-03  6.5 3950.0
2007-01-04  7.5 3960.0
2007-01-05  8.5 4000.0
2007-01-06  6.0 4000.0
```

This is my data set.
Start Date: `2007-01-02`
End Date:    `2017-12-31`

Data contain missing values, so I am trying to fill with moving average 5.
So I crate this new data frame, and how I fill this with moving average window 5?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `Date` column values are in `datetime64[ns]` type and set as `index`.

Firstly prepare a dataframe `date` using `start` and `end` dates and `merge()` it with the `df`

```
date = (pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2007-01-02', end='2017-12-31'))
        .rename(columns={0: 'Date'})
        .set_index('Date')
        )
df = date.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

And then fill the `nan` values with rolling means of `window` size of `5` (I set minimum required value of `1` but this is your choice)

```
df.Q.fillna(df.Q.rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean(), inplace=True)
df.Mod.fillna(df.Mod.rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: how to re-index the date, with start and end date. why i am asking this because panda automatically detect some dates which data has not register and panda remove them...